Spring Security 6 and 403 Forbidden with "requestMatchers"
Working on course project with SpringBoot and Spring Security. Have a problem that many people have encountered, but I couldn't handle it no matter how many other questions I looked at on the same topic.
All requests that I do to my api protected by "hasRole" or "authenticated" doesn't work properly. Postman always says 403 Forbidden even if operations are completed (for example, if I try to delete user by ID -> http://localhost:8080/api/users/example_id it works properly and removes the object from DB but Postman always return 403 Forbidden to me, the same for the other operations with /api). Of course it works fine if I change requestMatchers to permitAll()

SecurityConfig.kt
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    private val authenticationProvider: AuthenticationProvider
) {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
        jwtFilter: JwtFilter
    ): DefaultSecurityFilterChain =
        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { auth ->
                auth
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER") //authenticated() doesn't work too
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            }
            .sessionManagement { session ->
                session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .build()
}

JwtFilter.kt
@Component
class JwtFilter(
    private val userDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
    private val tokenService: TokenService
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val authHeader: String? = request.getHeader("Authorization")

        if (authHeader.doesNotContainBearerToken()) {
            logger.debug("No Bearer token found in the request")
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            return
        }

        val jwtToken = authHeader!!.extractTokenValue()
        logger.info("Token: $jwtToken")
        val email = tokenService.extractEmail(jwtToken)

        if (email != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication == null) {
            logger.debug("Attempting to authenticate user: $email")
            val foundUser = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email)

            if (tokenService.isValid(jwtToken, foundUser)) {
                updateContext(foundUser, request)
                logger.info("Token is valid. User authenticated: $email")
            } else {
                logger.warn("Invalid token for user: $email")
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        }

        val auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
        logger.info("Authentication status: ${auth?.isAuthenticated}, User: ${auth?.name}, Authorities: ${auth?.authorities}")
    }

    private fun updateContext(foundUser: UserDetails, request: HttpServletRequest) {
        val authToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(foundUser, null, foundUser.authorities)
        authToken.details = WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authToken
        logger.info("Updated context: $authToken")
    }

    private fun String?.doesNotContainBearerToken(): Boolean =
        this == null || !this.startsWith("Bearer ")

    private fun String.extractTokenValue(): String =
        this.substringAfter("Bearer ")
}

CustomUserDetailsService
typealias ApplicationUser = com.example.dbtest.domain.models.User

@Service
class CustomUserDetailsService(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) : UserDetailsService {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenService::class.java)

    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails = runBlocking {
        loadUserByUsernameAsync(username)
    }

    private suspend fun loadUserByUsernameAsync(username: String): UserDetails {
        logger.info("Loading User: $username")
        val user = userRepository.findByEmail(username).firstOrNull()
            ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found: $username")

        logger.info("User Found. Email: ${user.email}")
        return user.toUserDetails()
    }


    private fun ApplicationUser.toUserDetails(): UserDetails {
        return User.builder()
            .username(this.email)
            .password(this.passwordHash)
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
    }
}

And TokenService
@Service
class TokenService(
    private val jwtProperties: JwtProperties
) {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenService::class.java)

    private val secretKey by lazy {
        Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtProperties.key.toByteArray()).also {
            logger.debug("Secret key initialized with algorithm: ${it.algorithm}")
        }
    }

    fun generateAccessToken(
        userDetails: UserDetails,
        expirationDate: Date,
        additionalClaims: Map<String, Any> = emptyMap()
    ): String {
        val token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userDetails.username)
            .setIssuedAt(Date())
            .setExpiration(expirationDate)
            .addClaims(additionalClaims)
            .signWith(secretKey)
            .compact()
        logger.debug("Generated token for user ${userDetails.username}: $token")
        return token
    }

    fun isValid(token: String, userDetails: UserDetails): Boolean {
        val email = extractEmail(token)
        val isValid = email == userDetails.username && !isExpired(token)
        logger.debug("Token validity for user ${userDetails.username}: $isValid")
        return isValid
    }

    fun extractEmail(token: String): String? =
        getAllClaims(token).subject.also {
            logger.debug("Extracted email from token: $it")
        }

    fun isExpired(token: String): Boolean =
        getAllClaims(token).expiration.before(Date()).also {
            logger.debug("Token expired: $it")
        }

    private fun getAllClaims(token: String): Claims {
        return try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(secretKey)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .body
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse JWT token: $token", ex)
            throw ex
        }
    }
}

As you can see I added a lot of logs and there I can see that user with bearer token inserted in Postman is authenticated but still the only thing Postman returns to me is 403 Forbidden. I'm trying to fix it.
Logs:
2024-09-14T10:36:17.431+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.service.TokenService   : Loading User: saul@example.com
2024-09-14T10:36:17.853+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.service.TokenService   : User Found. Email: saul@example.com
2024-09-14T10:36:17.860+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.security.JwtFilter     : Updated context: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=saul@example.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2024-09-14T10:36:17.860+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.security.JwtFilter     : Token is valid. User authenticated: saul@example.com
2024-09-14T10:36:17.910+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.service.TokenService   : Controller (within coroutine) - Authentication status: true, Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=saul@example.com, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2024-09-14T10:36:17.929+03:00  INFO 17060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.security.JwtFilter     : Authentication status: true, User: saul@example.com, Authorities: [ROLE_USER]

And debug logs:
2024-09-14T20:11:20.841+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users?nickname=john_doe
2024-09-14T20:11:20.846+03:00  INFO 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.dbtest.domain.security.JwtFilter     : JwtToken: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzYXVsQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNzI2MzMyNDg0LCJleHAiOjE3MjYzMzYwODR9._TmJGi_Aw9NfoqoMSgdwMjgQJ75Hxpgld3UmS6A8_YNRo2DCYRy29PqorxOoXIrk0fPhQT8JhwrpHa4WI_pnSw
2024-09-14T20:11:21.359+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/users?nickname=john_doe
2024-09-14T20:11:21.433+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users?nickname=john_doe
2024-09-14T20:11:21.434+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-14T20:11:21.434+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-09-14T20:11:21.436+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?nickname=john_doe
2024-09-14T20:11:21.436+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error?nickname=john_doe
2024-09-14T20:11:21.475+03:00 DEBUG 14028 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

I suppose first request is correctly responded but there's another one which is the reason of 403 Forbidden status code.

did you try adding "/error" to your requestMatchers ?
